# I can't seem to draw a line on html5 canvas

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I am using HTML5 for drawing a line. But it is not working properly in chrome when the width and height of the canvas is large.

I am using chrome 19.0.1084.52 and my os is windows 7.

Has anyone used http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_line for testing?

If you increase the width and height of the canvas the line disappears.

Is there any maximum height and width for canvas in chrome and does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

It's an interesting issue!

After testing with my Chrome and Firefox, I find that:

- **Chrome** draws nothing if canvas width > **32767**
- **Firefox** draws nothing if canvas width > **32766**

If your canvas width is greater than that number, nothing will be drawn.

I don't know why there is such a limitation.
Maybe we can find out the root cause by the browser's source code!

The following code is an example. You can [click here to run it](http://jsfiddle.net/4c75a/13/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

If canvas width is greater than 32767, Chrome can't draw anything.<br>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="32768" height="100"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">    
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.moveTo(10,50);
ctx.lineTo(300,50);
ctx.stroke();    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

there may be a width and height limitation, but i feel it is enough,

here it is http://jsfiddle.net/AkashSaikia/4c75a/

It have played with large size

And as per w3c here
its like this with unsigned long that is about  0 to 4,294,967,295

```
interface HTMLCanvasElement : HTMLElement {
           attribute unsigned long width;
           attribute unsigned long height;

  DOMString toDataURL(optional DOMString type, any... args);
  void toBlob(FileCallback? _callback, optional DOMString type, any... args);

  object? getContext(DOMString contextId, any... args);
};
```

but as tested once it takes about 0 to 2147483647

see here http://jsfiddle.net/AkashSaikia/9EWad/1/

And when or how are you changing the height and width of the Canavas?

FIY , if you change height and width property of canvas, then it will clear the things drawn over it.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>    Can you test this code. It is not working my browser

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="1000" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(320,50);
ctx.lineTo(10,50);
ctx.stroke();

</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: The above code is not working my chrome. I only chnaged the size of the canvas width to 600 and height 1000. ande line drawn form 10,10 to 320,50 and back to 10,50 .

Comment: here you can see http://jsfiddle.net/AkashSaikia/6wHj2/

Its working, whats the problem...

Comment: This is not working in my system. I am using chrome 19.0.1084.52 and windows 7 os.

Comment: The key thing here for me was changing the width and height of the canvas after drawing some lines (I had to based on dynamic content).  IE handles this fine.  Chrome and Firefox can't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maximum width and height for the line which may depend on the used browser.

If you want to draw very wide line then you draw a rectangle and transform it to the correct position and rotate it to the line angle.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience, there exists a size limitation for canvas rendering, at least for iOS device. This is due to the limited GPU memory as the canvas is usually hardware accelerated nowadays.

For iOS device, the max size will be 5 MegaPixel for devices with 256+MB memory, 3 MegaPixel for devices with less memory.