# What is causing my canvas drawing to break and skip at certain values (2^15, for one)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, matrix, easeljs

I'm working on a 2d canvas-based app using EaselJS where the user can move indefinitely on the xy-plane by dragging the background.  Think google maps, except the background is a repeating tile.

The code for the movement is very simple and looks something like this:

```
// container  - the createjs.Container being panned
// background - a createjs.Shape child of container, on which the 
//              background is drawn
background.onPress = function(evt) {
  var x = evt.stageX, y = evt.stageY;

  evt.onMouseMove = function(evt) {
    // the canvas is positioned in the center of the window, so the apparent 
    // movement works by changing the registration point of the container in 
    // the opposite direction.
    container.regX -= evt.stageX - x;
    container.regY -= evt.stageY - y;
    x = evt.stageX;
    y = evt.stageY;
    stage.update();
  };

  evt.onMouseUp = function(evt) {
    // Here the background would be redrawn based on the new container coords.  
    // However the issue occurs even before the mouse is released.
    background.redraw();
    stage.update();
  };
};
```

All works as expected *until* reaching 32678px (2^15) on either axis.  What occurs is different in different browsers, but the point where it first happens is the same.

In Firefox, it will suddenly shift a large chunk of pixels (~100) rather than 1. It will then happen again at 65538 (2^16+2), perhaps more after that, but I haven't witnessed it.  After the trouble points, the drag will continue smoothly, as expected, but remaining shifted.

In Chrome, the effect is more dramatic.  The drawing breaks and results in repeated ~100px wide "stripes" of the background across the page at 32768, and does not correct itself on redraw.

Oddly, the numbers in EaselJS don't reflect the issue.  The only change in the container's transform matrix is the `tx` or `ty` incrementing by 1. No other matrices change.  It *seems* as though EaselJS is getting all the numbers right.

Can anyone shed any light this issue?

**Edit:**
I worked around this problem by redrawing parts of the container using a calculated regX/regY, rather than attempting to translate very large regX/regY coords on the canvas.

Comment: +1; Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I can give it a shot tomorrow, but unfortunately it's not trivial.  I'd have to break a bunch of code out of my app and put it back together to get a fiddle going.  The actual canvas code involved though is fairly minimal.  It's a container containing the one background shape, which draws a rect with a repeating canvas fill around the whole thing, then moves the container's registration point on drag (as in the code above).

Answer (score 1):

This question may be related

[What is the maximum size for an HTML canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259108/what-is-the-maximum-size-for-an-html-canvas)

From what I gather browsers use `short int` to store canvas sizes with 32,767 being the maximum possible value.

Links possibly related to your issue,

- [Mozilla - HTML5 Canvas slow/out of memory](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649924)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535564/149636

Comment: This seems to conspicuous to not be related.  The thing is that my canvas isn't that large, rather just the xy coordinates of a shape within it are.  Both browsers will actually extend well beyond that number (into the hundreds of thousands, at least).  In firefox I just have the issue of a mystery shift, and in chrome, oddly, I've found that if the scale is not 1, I can drag straight through 2^15 (and 2^15*scale just to be sure) with no issues at all.